# SQL Connection Timeout Expired

Tags: sql-server, clustering

We have a strange issue with our SQL server.
We have two SQL nodes (node 1 and node 2) configured in Microsoft Cluster.
It's important to note that the issue is only with one of the nodes. When the SQL roles are on the node 1 -> there is no issue, but when the SQL roles are on the node 2 -> the issue comes.

We have an application server from where we connect to our SQL server.
The errors that we see on the application server (Source server) are:

[image: application error log]

The errors that we see in the SQL server logs are:

[image: SQL error log]

Could someone help me with the issue above?
Any pointers on what the problem could be considering the problem only occurs on one node. Until now it has always worked well, but since 1 month this problem has appeared.

The issue appears every day at same time range from 7 to 9 AM

Comment: What do you have for SQL Agent jobs that run over 7am-9am?

Comment: @vonPryz yes, the validation is happy there are no issues. The SQL roles can be successfully migrated between the two nodes.

Comment: @ErikDarling there are standard SQL jobs that are running every day. As I already mentioned, when the SQL roles are on the "Node 1" there is no issue with SQL timeout. But when they are on "Node 2" there is a problem. I think the issue is network related but this is a long shot.

Comment: @DimitarStoykov "standard SQL jobs" doesn't tell me much.

Comment: Much as I stated on the previous question on the same thing https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/335362/microsoft-sql-cluster-database-problem You'll want to get a packet capture from each side and to your authentication source as well.

Comment: @SeanGallardy Could you please describe how this process should go? I'm not aware of how to do it

Comment: This is outside of SQL Server (packet captures). Everyone has their favorite, Wireshark is very common. Regardless, you'll want to also capture server metrics, cpu, disk, etc., and SQL metrics such as sys.dm_os_schedulers, sys.dm_exec_requests, etc., and look at the map holistically. If this is all new to you, it may make sense to seek professional help.

Comment: Is the agent using native SQL auth or AD style external? If the AD is not responding in a timely manner, you might get this timeout, hence SeanGallardy's recommendation of the packet traces. The 2x servers do not necessarily interact with the same logon servers.